# Why Equals(null) fail on object array null check

Tags: c#, object, null, comparison

I have an object array as follows:

```
private object[] _yazdirmaBilgisi = new object[5];
```

On some point I want to access the first element but of course I wanna check if it is null first

At some point [0] is null but [1] is not null.

When I check if the value is null with `Equals` it throws exception:

```
if (!_yazdirmaBilgisi[0].Equals(null))  //Throws exception
```

But if i check with `!=` null ne exception

```
if (_yazdirmaBilgisi[0] != null) // No exception
```

Why does it differ?
Why `Equals(null)` throws exception but `!= null` doesn't

Comment: `_yazdirmaBilgisi[0].Equals` means you are trying to call instance method `Equals` and since `_yazdirmaBilgisi[0]` is null, you get NRE

Comment: @Habib Even if it's short, you may post it as an answer^^

Comment: and what exception does it throw? So you can answer your own question.

Comment: Be clear please, we have to guess what is wrong with your code to answer.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I don't think he's saying something is wrong with his code, he's just asking WHY the two different checks produce different results.  Seems like more of a newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
if (!_yazdirmaBilgisi[0].Equals(null))
```

1. Extracts a reference from `_yazdirmaBilgisi[0]`
2. Uses that reference as the object on which to call `.Equals()`.

But because that reference is `null`, it throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Whereas:

```
if (_yazdirmaBilgisi[0] != null)
```

is directly comparing the reference in `_yazdirmaBilgisi[0]` with null, so it doesn't throw an exception - it is not trying to call any methods of the referenced object.

Answer (score 3):

Because `== null` isn't the same as `.Equals(null)`. If you use `Equals`, you will obviously get an exception because of trying to access null reference. `==` works different, similar to `Object.Equals(a,b)` in that it checks if both values are null first, then it does more comparing.

Answer (score 1):

The first throws because the first element in the list is a null reference.  This is what your code is doing:

```
var element = _yazdirmaBilgisi[0];
if (element.Equals(null)) // element is null, and null.Equals is calling a method on a null reference
```

The == operator is defined to do something similar to this:

```
var element = _yazdirmaBilgisi[0]; // element is reference who's value is null
if (object.ReferenceEquals(element, null)) // object.Equals is a static method which doesn't require an object instance
```

Comment: *The == operator is overloaded to do this* is misleading.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I removed the term overload, but otherwise how is it misleading?

Comment: Now that's fine. Not only the term *overloaded* was misleading, you said it is overloaded to do `object.Equals`, that's wrong. Later you changed it to `ReferenceEquals`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I'm not sure I like ReferenceEquals either (which is why I said my code is similar).  In the question he's explicitly using System.Objects, but Strings do define the == operator and it'd be a bit more complicated than my sample.